# ActionScript displaying images from a certain URL

Tags: image, url, actionscript

I'm having difficulty displaying an image with a given URL. does anyone have an idea on how to display an image on actionscript? thank you very much! someone told me to use `Loader` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a tutorial [here](http://blog.nichmekof.com/2008/05/load-image-with-actionscript-3/).